# What is The difference of xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier and xgboost.XGBClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model, xgboost, data-science-model

### `xgboost.sklearn` VS `xgboost.XGBClassifier`

Here is my code that I tried to train `make_moons` datset from `sklearn.datasets` and see the difference of this to functions, but it made the same results:

Data:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import model_selection
X, y = datasets.make_moons(n_samples=100000, noise=0.4, random_state=341)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=431)
```

Classifiers:

```
xgb1 = xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier(max_depth=2)
xgb2 = xgboost.XGBClassifier(max_depth=2)
```

Train Part:

```
xgb1.fit(x_train, y_train)
xgb2.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Test Part:

```
print(xgb1.score(x_test, y_test))
print(xgb2.score(x_test, y_test))
```

Results:

```
xgb1:   0.8626
xgb2:   0.8626
```

As you can see, The Results are the same so, why there are two different ways of them to approach? If they are different, can you explain what is the difference? And which is more preferable to use? My Problem isn't about classifier itself, it is about only `xgboost.sklearn`, I want to know may I use only `xgboost` or `xgboost.sklearn`? And why?

Answer (score 4):

They are exactly the same and provide a `scikit-learn` API to their xgboost model instead of the learning API that is also available. You can see in [the source code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/__init__.py#L17) that in `xgboost` they are importing the `XGBClassifier` from `xgboost.sklearn`, which is exactly the same model as you are using as your second model. With regards to which of the two to use, since they are exactly the same it doesn't really matter but I would probably use `xgboost.XGBClassifier` since that is the class that is already exposed at the top level of the package.